# Given a root node, how to delete the unreachable component (nodes) in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am doing graph analysis using `neo4j`, and I am thinking to delete all the dead components given a root node.

I know I can load the whole graph in the memory, do a `bfs` starting from the root node, keep all the reached nodes in a list, and after the traversal, trim off the graph by only keeping the reached nodes.

But I suppose this approach is not memory efficiency, as I am working on millions of nodes. So, I am wondering, does `neo4j` provide such functionality to delete the unreachable components from a given root node? Thank you!

Comment: Is a "dead component" an orphan node (a node with 0 relationships)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Neo4j doesn't provide such a functionality directly.

You can do it yourself using a Cypher query, but yes, it will be costly, especially if you have a large graph.

## Naive implementation

The most naive version would be:

```
MATCH (root), (n)
WHERE id(root) = {rootId}
  AND n <> root
  AND NOT (n)-[*]-(root)
DETACH DELETE n
```

If you need to delete a large number of nodes, you probably want to introduce a `LIMIT` to ensure you don't create a huge transaction which could lead to an OutOfMemory error. The query would have to be repeated until it finds nothing to delete:

```
MATCH (root), (n)
WHERE id(root) = {rootId}
  AND n <> root
  AND NOT (n)-[*]-(root)
WITH n
LIMIT 1000
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN count(n)
```

### Performance

The unbounded traversal (`-[*]-`) can (will) lead to performance problems.

The traversal also needs to be repeated for each and every node (full node scan), which will be costly (at least like *O(n^2)*) if most nodes *are connected* to the root node, or if unconnected subgraphs are also large.

### Execution plan

I happen to have a graph on which I can simulate your use case.

Running a slightly modified query (with an upper bound on the variable-length relationship, as my graph is totally connected):

```
PROFILE MATCH (root), (n)
WHERE id(root) = 0
  AND n <> root
  AND NOT (n)-[*..6]-(root) 
RETURN count(n);
```

yields the following execution plan:

```
+--------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| Operator                 | Estimated Rows | Rows    | DB Hits   | Variables           | Other            |
+--------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| +ProduceResults          |            561 |       1 |         0 | count(n)            | count(n)         |
| |                        +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| +EagerAggregation        |            561 |       1 |         0 | count(n)            |                  |
| |                        +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply           |         314573 | 1392640 |         0 | n, root             |                  |
| |\                       +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| | +VarLengthExpand(Into) |              2 |       0 | 378135900 | anon[63] -- n, root | (n)-[:*]->(root) |
| | |                      +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| | +Argument              |        1258291 | 1398100 |         0 | n, root             |                  |
| |                        +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| +Filter                  |        1258291 | 1398100 |         0 | n, root             | NOT(n == root)   |
| |                        +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| +CartesianProduct        |        1398101 | 1398101 |         0 | root -- n           |                  |
| |\                       +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| | +AllNodesScan          |        1398101 | 1398101 |   1398102 | n                   |                  |
| |                        +----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+
| +NodeByIdSeek            |              1 |       1 |         1 | root                |                  |
+--------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+------------------+

Total database accesses: 379534003
```

and finds 1392640 nodes to delete in about **2 minutes and 20 seconds** (from a total of 1398101 nodes).

## Mark and sweep

Instead of traversing from each node to try and find a path to the root node, why not traverse once and for all from the root node, marking connected nodes, and deleting all the unreachable ones at the end? Just like a garbage collector.

Presented as a single query (hence the `WITH count(n) AS dummy` separators):

```
MATCH (n) SET n:Unreachable
WITH count(n) AS dummy
MATCH (root)-[*0..]-(n:Unreachable)
WHERE id(root) = {rootId}
REMOVE n:Unreachable
WITH count(n) AS dummy
MATCH (n:Unreachable)
DETACH DELETE n
```

Note the variable-length relationship starting at 0 to match the root itself and remove its `Unreachable` label.

### Performance

There's now a full node scan, a **single** traversal (still unbounded), and a label scan. If you know the maximum length of the shortest path between any 2 nodes (because of your model), you can set an upper bound on the variable-length relationship and limit the number of paths traversed.

### Execution plan

Once again, running a slightly modified query on my graph:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n)
SET n:Unreachable
WITH count(n) AS dummy
MATCH (root)-[*0..6]-(n:Unreachable)
WHERE id(root) = 0
REMOVE n:Unreachable
WITH count(n) AS dummy
MATCH (n:Unreachable)
RETURN count(n);
```

yields the following execution plan:

```
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows    | DB Hits | Variables                  | Other                 |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |           8209 |       1 |       0 | count(n)                   | count(n)              |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |           8209 |       1 |       0 | count(n)                   |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +Apply                |       67391877 | 1392640 |       0 | dummy -- n                 |                       |
| |\                    +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| | +NodeByLabelScan    |       67391877 | 1392640 | 1392641 | n                          | :Unreachable          |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |             48 |       1 |       0 | dummy                      |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +Eager                |                |    5461 |       0 | anon[64], dummy, n, root   |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +RemoveLabels         |           2342 |    5461 |    5461 | anon[64], dummy, n, root   |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +Filter               |           2342 |    5461 |    5461 | anon[64], dummy, n, root   | n:Unreachable         |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |           2342 |    5461 |    8189 | anon[64], n -- dummy, root | (root)-[:*]->(  n@73) |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +Apply                |           2342 |       1 |       0 | dummy -- root              |                       |
| |\                    +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| | +NodeByIdSeek       |           1182 |       1 |       1 | root                       |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |           1182 |       1 |       0 | dummy                      |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +Eager                |                | 1398101 |       0 | n                          |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +SetLabels            |        1398101 | 1398101 | 1398101 | n                          |                       |
| |                     +----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| +AllNodesScan         |        1398101 | 1398101 | 1398102 | n                          |                       |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------+

Total database accesses: 4207956
```

and also finds 1392640 nodes to delete (phew!) in about **4 seconds**.

That's 35 times faster! And the DB accesses have been reduced by a factor of 90!

---

### Update

If you have a large number of nodes to delete, you'll need to split the execution into smaller batches, executed until they have nothing to do anymore. Obviously you can't use a single query for that.

1. Prepare the graph:

   ```
   MATCH (n) SET n:Unreachable
   ```

   If that cannot be executed in a single pass, then execute this query until it returns 0:

   ```
   MATCH (n)
   WHERE NOT n:Unreachable
   WITH n
   LIMIT 10000
   SET n:Unreachable
   RETURN count(n)
   ```
2. Mark the nodes reachable from the root, again executing the query until it returns 0:

   ```
   MATCH (root)-[*0..]-(n:Unreachable)
   WHERE id(root) = {rootId}
   WITH n
   LIMIT 10000
   REMOVE n:Unreachable
   RETURN count(n)
   ```

   Of course, because it will have to traverse the same paths again and again to cover the whole subgraph connected to the root node, it will take longer than a single pass.
3. Delete the unreachable nodes, until there aren't any left:

   ```
   MATCH (n:Unreachable)
   WITH n
   LIMIT 10000
   DETACH DELETE n
   RETURN count(n)
   ```

---

### Update 2

Actually, step 2 will spend a lot of time traversing the same paths again and again in search of nodes still labelled with `Unreachable`, which gives us a *O(n^2)* algorithm again. We could instead propagate a "wave" of reachable nodes, until we've found nowhere to go.

1. Start with the root node, which is obviously reachable:

   ```
   MATCH (root)
   WHERE id(root) = {rootId}
   SET b:Reachable
   REMOVE n:Unreachable
   ```
2. Propagate "in circles", until we've covered the whole connected subgraph:

   ```
   MATCH (n:Reachable)
   WITH n
   LIMIT 1000
   OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(u:Unreachable)
   SET u:Reachable
   REMOVE u:Unreachable
   REMOVE n:Reachable
   RETURN count(DISTINCT n)
   ```

   Because we're removing the `Reachable` label as soon as we've expanded the wave, at the end there won't be any node left with that label and we don't have to clean up. And because we're matching nodes by label and traversing a single relationship, we're back to an *O(n)* algorithm.

   Here's how it looks on a sample graph, with the `LIMIT` set to 3 instead of 1000:

   [image: Wave propagation from the root node]

Comment: Hello Frank. Thank you so much for providing such awesome answer!! I tried your `Mark and sweep` method, and I got a "jave heap overflow " error. Are you by any chance aware of such issue..?

Comment: You probably have too many nodes to delete, and you'll need to split the execution into smaller batches (the equivalent of a `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` with `LOAD CSV`) as I mentioned in the naive implementation. Let me try and update the answer with that.

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know how it goes. Even it if slower than a single pass, it should still be much faster than the naive implementation.

Comment: And actually, I've updated it again, because the complexity of the algorithm kept nagging me.

Comment: Fantastic! I will try it soon. Thank you so much for such spectacular post!!